# warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used

Tags: c, fgets, c-strings, gets

Hi when I write make in the terminal I get this message. What is the problem with gets? Must I change something. Thanks for helping.

```
user@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Project$ make
gcc -g -ansi -pedantic -Wall -lm project.o -o project 
project.o: In function `main':
project.c:(.text+0x2c8c): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
```

```
void main(){
    char File_Name[55] = { "\0" };
    printf("Give Me File Name:\n");
    gets(File_Name);
    strcat(File_Name, ".as");
    Read_From_File(File_Name);
    printf("\n*******************************************\n");
    free_malloc();
}
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Comment: *What is the problem with gets?* It is dangerous and should not be used. The message tells you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function gets is unsafe and is not supported by the C standard. The used array can be overwritten beyond its size. Instead use the function fgets. That is instead of this statement

```
gets(File_Name);
```

write at least like

```
fgets( File_Name, sizeof( File_Name ), stdin );
```

The function can append the new line character '\n' to the entered string. To remove it use the following code

```
#include <string.h>

//...

fgets( File_Name, sizeof( File_Name ), stdin );

File_Name[ strcspn( File_Name, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

Take into account that this initialization

```
char File_Name[55] = { "\0" };
```

is equivalent to

```
char File_Name[55] = "";
```

or to

```
char File_Name[55] = { '\0' };
```

Comment: This is a workaround to the problem the OP is has, but it doesn't answer the question: '_What is the problem with gets?_'

Comment: Thanks for the help Vlad!

Comment: Note that the `fgets()` approach obliges an array size one larger to handle a filename of 54 characters without leaving the `'\n'` in `stdin`.